# Add Table caption to a figure to IEEEtran

Tags: tables, floats, ieeetran

I am using **IEEEtran** document class.

I want to import a figure and give it caption of table i.e. Table 1

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Table 1}
\Figure[h!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){fig1.png}
\end{table}
```

Does it possible? Or any other way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you sure about the syntax (and the existence) of `\Figure`? I can't see it defined in `IEEEtran.cls`

Comment: `table` and `figure` don't care for what are their contents. So you could use `\begin{table}\caption{Table 1}\includegraphics{fig1.png}\end{table}`.

Comment: It looks like `\Figure` could be from `easyfig`. But no matter where this command comes from, the `[h!]` looks like this is a float internally, and if that's the case, your code doesn't work, because you can't include a `figure` environment inside a `table`.

Answer (score 2):

The caption version is controlled from the environments `table` and `figure`. If you have `table` it will be a table caption. You can include a picture into that, but use the `graphicx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption{Test of table caption}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \label{tab:MyTable}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Test of figure caption}
  \label{tab:MyFigure}
\end{figure}
In Table~\ref{tab:MyTable} it is a table caption and in Figure~\ref{tab:MyFigure} it is a figure caption.
\end{document}
```

[image]